# App does not compile in X64 (but correctly in X86) after Toolkit.UWP update to V5.0

Tags: compilation, 64-bit, windows-community-toolkit

After update of Toolkit (and Windows 10 SDK) app does not compile in X64 (but works correctly in X86). Here are the errors:

> ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.1\tools\x64\ilc\Tools\rhbind.exe @"C:\Users\pierr\source\repos\Mon Gestionnaire de Photos\Mon Gestionnaire de Photos\obj\x64\Debug\ilc\intermediate\rhbindargs.Mon Gestionnaire de Photos.rsp"' returned exit code 7

and

> RHBIND : error RHB0007: Could not load input file 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.srclink'.

Comment: Hello, I am having exactly the same problem.   Have you found a solution?

Comment: No; tried reinstalling everything VS, SDK, Toolkit problem remains

Comment: Thank you for the information. FYI, I posted a thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c853eaca-deeb-433d-896a-58be300dea45/uwpc-error-rhb0007-could-not-load-input-file-microsofttoolkituwpuisrclink?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I think it is a bug in the compiler that it trips when the name of the app contains a space. Can we try remove the space in the path and see if it compiles?

Comment: 6.2.2 is no longer available from nuget

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar [issues](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/c853eaca-deeb-433d-896a-58be300dea45/uwpc-error-rhb0007-could-not-load-input-file-microsofttoolkituwpuisrclink?forum=wpdevelop), Downgrading Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform  from 6.2.2 to 6.1.9 resolves the issues.

The real issue was from a dependent package of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.2 : "Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler/2.2.1" whereas the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.1.9 depends on "Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler/2.1.8"